# IMemoryCache without MVC

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

From this code, which takes data from a database, I extract the fields that interest me and show them to the video.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.ProductList)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td onclick="myFunction(this)" class="view-message  dont-show"><h5>@item.Id</h5></td>
                                <td onclick="myFunction(this)" class="view-message"><h5>@item.Name</h5></td>
                                <td onclick="myFunction(this)"><h4 style="margin-top: 5px;"><span class="label label-success ">@item.Model</span></h4></td>
                                <td onclick="myFunction(this)" class="view-message  text-left"><h5>@item.Price</h5></td>
                                <td>
                                    <form method="post">
                                        <span class="btn-group pull-right" style="margin-top: 5px">
                                            <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" asp-page="/Product/Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" style="background-color: green; height: 29px; margin-top: -1px;">
                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                                            </a>

                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" asp-page-handler="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id" style="height: 27px; margin-top: 0px;"
                                                    onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this product?');">
                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                                            </button>

                                        </span>
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
```

Question: How can I enter this data in cache (IMemoryCache)?

I use Core 2.1 and I would like to avoid using MVC and then using "controllers".

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: *“I would like to avoid using MVC and then using ‘controllers’.”* – If you want to avoid MVC, what do you want to use instead?

Comment: Hello poke,
I would like to avoid using "controllers", using Razor (PageModel) with dependency injection.

Comment: What is **enter this data in cache**? Do you mean you want to post data from view to `PageModel` and cache it in `IMemoryCache`? Please check [Cache in-memory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.1), is there any issue with this doc to implement your requirement?

Comment: Yes, right! I would like to insert the data that, at the moment I am in the view, in IMemoryCache.

I have read the Microsoft documentation, but the example refers only to the MVC, so with the use of controllers. I can not extrapolate it from the controller so I can use it in a PageModel

Comment: You can use pretty much any code inside a controller action in the code-behind of a Razor Page. So you should be able to just copy it over.